Cannot access 'com.unity3d.player.IUnityPlayerLifecycleEvents'
I am trying to export an Android project from Unity to use XR in an Android application. When I copy the project over from Unity, I am unable to reference com.unity3d.player.IUnityPlayerLifecycleEvents. What am I doing wrong?
(app:)Build.Gradle.kts
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application)
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrains.kotlin.android)
}

android {
    namespace = "com.project.unitytest2"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.project.unitytest2"
        minSdk = 30
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        getByName("main") {
            jniLibs.srcDirs("src/main/jniLibs", "libs/unityLibrary/src/main/jniLibs")
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.5.1"
    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation(libs.androidx.core.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.lifecycle.runtime.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.activity.compose)
    implementation(platform(libs.androidx.compose.bom))
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui)
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui.graphics)
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui.tooling.preview)
    implementation(libs.androidx.material3)
    implementation(project(":unityLibrary"))
    testImplementation(libs.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.espresso.core)
    androidTestImplementation(platform(libs.androidx.compose.bom))
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.test.junit4)
    debugImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.tooling)
    debugImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.test.manifest)
}

(project) build.gradle.kts
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrains.kotlin.android) apply false
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.31")
    }
}

settings.gradle.kts
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google {
            content {
                includeGroupByRegex("com\\.android.*")
                includeGroupByRegex("com\\.google.*")
                includeGroupByRegex("androidx.*")
            }
        }
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.name = "Unity Test 2"
include(":app", ":unityLibrary")
project(":unityLibrary").projectDir = file("unityLibrary")

ArActivity.kt
package com.project.unitytest2

import com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity

class ArActivity : UnityPlayerActivity() {
    ...
}

// Cannot access 'com.unity3d.player.IUnityPlayerLifecycleEvents' which is a supertype of
// 'com.project.unitytest2.ArActivity'. Check your module classpath for missing or 
// conflicting dependencies


Project structure
app/
  kotlin+java/
    com.project.unitytest2
      ArActivity
      MainActivity.kt
unityLibrary/

